# How to Avoid the Blender game engine starts when opening a blend file

Tags: blender, blender-2.61

I have been watching a tutorial for a game in blender, but when I open the blend file it automatically starts the game engine, is there a way to bypass this?

this is the source file.

http://www.neisd.net/ksat/studentwork/blender/niland/sam_game.blend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `-Y` command line switch. To quote from the [blender wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.5/Doc/Command_Line_Arguments):

```
-Y or --disable-autoexec 
    Disable automatic python script execution (pydrivers, pyconstraints, pynodes)
```

Beware! That is an uppercase `Y`

Comment: I try to put that command but Blneder wont allow it, Is there other way?

Comment: What do you mean with "Blender wont allow it"? I tried it with your file and got no problems